# Convert date field to days, hours, and minutes

Tags: sql-server

I need to get `date` field data like `23 5:22` days, hours, minutes. The below conversion is working in `ORACLE` but I need same conversion in `SQL Server`.

```
TO_CHAR ( TRUNC (SYSDATE) + MOD (SYSDATE - subc.creation_time , 1 ), 'HH24: MI' )
```

How would I go about doing this?

Comment: What version of Sql Server? Newer releases have easier support for this via the FORMAT() function while older releases will require complicated CONVERT() expressions.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this?

```
DECLARE @creation_time  datetime = '2017-12-11 16:52:30';
SELECT FORMAT( @creation_time , 'dd HH:mm');
```

This returns:

```
11 16:52
```

More info here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/format-transact-sql

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT SUBSTRING(CONVERT(CHAR(16),subc.creation_time, 20), 9, 8)
```

At the current time `2017-12-11 16:51:50.763` it gets me

```
11 16:51
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also try with if you working on earlier versions:

```
SELECT
    DATENAME(Day, GetDate()) + ' '+ CONVERT(VARCHAR(5),GetDate(), 108) AS Result;
```